# DAX function to count if a cell value begins with a certain character

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need a function that allows me to count how many rows, for a specific column, start with a specific letter.

For example:
I have a table with columns A, B, and C.
I want to count how many rows have a value starting with M in column B.

I am new to this and need to develop a DAX function.

Any idea of how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Count = 
COUNTROWS ( 
    FILTER ( 
        'Table' , 
        LEFT ( 'Table'[column B] , 1 ) = "M" )
    )
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make a temp table by filtering the column using a regex to match the first character.  Then count the rows in the temp table.

```
[test] = VAR tempTable =
            FILTER ( 'Table', IsMatch('Table'[B],"^M",MatchOptions.Contains)))
        RETURN
            COUNTROWS ( tempTable )
```